# Xamarin Safe way to call async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I have this one section where I want to wait to make sure this task is completed. I have added the task.wait but it seems that the await in the task are not getting completed.

> Is this getting me into a deadlock ? is there a better way to do this?

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => DataSynchronize.SyncLinks());
task.Wait();
if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
Preferences.Set("IsUpdate", "True");
}
```

Model

```
public static async Task<Status> SyncLinks()
```

All Other section use this

```
await DataSynchronize.SyncLinks();
```

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: why not just await?

Comment: Do you mean Task task = Task.Run(async () => { await DataSynchronize.SyncLinks(); });

Comment: No I mean `await DataSynchronize.SyncLinks();` Why call blocking call `.Wait()` that can lead to deadlocks

Comment: But I wanted to make sure it is completed?

Comment: once it is completed I am going to updated the preferences

Comment: When the method hits the `await`, it will be paused until the task completes. When the method continues executing after the `await`, the task has been completed.

Comment: What Stephen and all mentioned. You should also take some time to familiarize yourself with async/await. Check out Stephen's blog  https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html and his book https://stephencleary.com/book/. Also check out the msdn article on it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/. Getting a fundamental understanding of async/await will save a lot of time in the future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment so adding here

await the task and check its status

```
Task<Status> task = DataSynchronize.SyncLinks();
await task;
if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {
    Preferences.Set("IsUpdate", "True");
}
```

Or better yet

just await the call

```
Status status = await DataSynchronize.SyncLinks();
if(...some condition based on status)
    Preferences.Set("IsUpdate", "True");
```

All in all, try to avoid mixing blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()` that can potentially cause deadlocks.